# mybatis : Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I'm studying spring mvc - mybatis application using spring 4.3.18.RELEASE, mybatis-spring 2.0.2 (also, IDE : intelliJ)

I checked the namespace, the location of the mapper, etc., but I couldn't solve the error.
I don't know what I'm missing.
I'd really appreciate it if you could help me.

I got the following error.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): org.example.HelloService.HelloService.getHello
```

**datasourceContext.xml**

```
...

    <bean id="SqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:/mappers/*.xml"/>

    </bean>

    <mybatis-spring:scan base-package="org.example"/>


    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate" destroy-method="clearCache">
        <constructor-arg ref="SqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd" >
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias alias="HelloDto" type="org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto"/>
    </typeAliases>
</configuration>
```

**helloMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="org.example.HelloMapper.HelloMapper">
    <select id="selectHello" resultType="org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto">
        select * from temp.temp_tbl
    </select>
</mapper>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package org.example.HelloController;

import org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto;
import org.example.HelloService.HelloService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloService helloService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model){
        List<HelloDto> helloList  = helloService.getHello();
        model.addAttribute("helloList", helloList);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**HelloService.java**

```
package org.example.HelloService;

import org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto;
import java.util.List;


public interface HelloService {
    List<HelloDto> getHello();
}
```

**HelloServiceImpl.java**

```
package org.example.HelloService.impl;

import org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto;
import org.example.HelloMapper.HelloMapper;
import org.example.HelloService.HelloService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService {

    @Autowired
    private HelloMapper helloMapper;

    @Override
    public List<HelloDto> getHello() {
        return helloMapper.selectHello();
    }
}
```

**HelloDto**

```
package org.example.HelloDto;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class HelloDto {
    private String id;
    private String password;

    public HelloDto(String id, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HelloDto{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**HelloMapper.java**

```
package org.example.HelloMapper;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.example.HelloDto.HelloDto;

import java.util.List;


@Mapper
public interface HelloMapper {

    List<HelloDto> selectHello();
}
```

It's a whole file structure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl7EV.png)

Comment: Those versions are incompatible (and very old). See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring/#requirements).